# Segue after Firebase Google LogIn Xcode 11

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new in this, i'm searching a solution to go to a new view controller after login with google. 
Login is working, i think, but after 3 days I'm not succeeded.
I want to go into other blank viewcontroller after login.
I have tried many solutions, found in stackoverflow and google documentation, but it seems that there isn't a documentation for my version of Xcode.

This is my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import FirebaseUI

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {



    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self

        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
              print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
            } else {
              print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return
          }
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let fullName = user.profile.name
            let givenName = user.profile.givenName
            let familyName = user.profile.familyName
            let email = user.profile.email
                print(fullName)

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("firebase sign in error")
                print(error)
                return
            } else {
            print("user is signed in with Firebase")

            }

        }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
      -> Bool {
      return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }



    }

}
```

This is my ViewController

```
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ViewController: UIViewController{


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()
        super.viewDidAppear(true)


        let gSignIn = GIDSignInButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 230, height: 48))
        gSignIn.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(gSignIn)
    }

}
```

I would be very grateful to you if someone help.

Comment: Hi Stefano, you can use "window.rootViewController" after user is signed

Comment: I have implemented this in appdelegate, there is no error but is still not working..
 let storyboard = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard
                    let mainPage = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "new")

                  
                    self.window?.rootViewController = mainPage

Comment: Did you set identifier your signedViewController  in storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
var vc: UIViewController?
vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signed")
window?.rootViewController = vc
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: I also tried with this code, i implemented this in a "login" function and i call the function after print("user is signed in with Firebase").
I have no errors, but there is always the same view on my simulator. I have the right id storybard identifier.

Comment: Dou you have scene Delegate in your project

Comment: This code doesn't work when project has scene delegate.

Comment: thank you mate, you've made my day, and my next day

Comment: Good luck, happy coding